# Asp.Net Core 3.1 - Remove And Rename jstree node by GUID value when button is clicked?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

This code displaying Category in Razor View :

```
 $('#evts_button').on("click", function () {
            var instance = $('#jstree').jstree(true);
            instance.deselect_all();
            console.log(instance);
        });
        $('#jstree')
            .on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
                if (data.selected.length) {
                    alert('The selected node is: ' + data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).id);
                }
            })
            .jstree({
                'core': {
                    'multiple': false,
                    "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json)
                    
                }
            });
```

I Have all of the nodes  in `instance.deselect_all();`

I want to put a button that sends the value to the controller when clicked?

Delete and rename the selected node?

this is consol log :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Used this :

```
$('#evts_button').on("click", function () {
       var instance = $('#jstree').jstree("get_selected");
    });
    $('#jstree')
        .on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
            if (data.selected.length) {
                alert('The selected node is: ' + data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).id);
            }
        })
        .jstree({
            'core': {
                'multiple': false,
                "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Json)
                
            }
        });
```

It's worked